# Symfony2 Date Field Year 

Tags: symfony, datefield

I am developing an application using Symfony2. The problem comes when creating a registration form that require to use a date field to indicate the date in which the user was born, the possible values for the year are in range 2007-2017. How can I modify this values the years to be for example,in the range 1920-actual year? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look up in [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/date.html) next time:

```
$builder->add('birthday', 'date', array(
    'years' => range(1920, date('Y'))
));
```

Comment: Didn't know about the range function. This is really neat!